# C++ avoid constructing an object

Tags: c++, constructor

I have an class whose all default constructors are beyond my control. I need to avoid constructing them in some conditions and not in others. Is there any what I can do this ?

The pattern is something like this:

```
class A
{
public: 
    //ctor + dtor + methods
    A(); 
    ~A();
    // Data members beyond my control
    X1 x1;
    X2 x2;
    ...
    XN xn;
};

class B
{
public:
    B()
    {}

    // Data members
    A a;   // This instance of A is the issue
};
```

The issue is `X1` to `XN` are completely beyond my control. Class `A` is just a class which packages `x1` to `xn` together. I want to conditionally create the instance of `A`, in `B`. Now the issue is that the default constructors of `X1` to `XN` do something that needs to be avoid under some conditions and not others. So no matter if I construct `A` or not, `B` will try to create a using the default constructor of `A`, which will in turn initiate default constructors of `X1` to `XN`. This is what I need to avoid.

I am using macros to fix this currently, but wanted to see if there is a better solution out there.

Comment: This question is too vague. What are the circumstances? As it stands: just use pointers.

Comment: If you don't want to create an instance of a class, don't write code that creates an instance of a class.

Comment: You can define the default constructor as private.  Look at the Singleton pattern in C++ to see how this can be done.

Comment: To build on what @unapersson said, what specifically are you trying to accomplish?  Is there any reason why objects would be constructed in areas you wouldn't want them?  Also, a default constructor is one that can be called without any arguments.  Is that what you mean, or do you mean constructors automatically provided by the compiler (which would include a copy constructor)?  If this turns into a real question, I'm willing to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a Nullable type like boost::optional. This would look like:

```
class B {
public:
    B()
    {
        /*
         * Here, a has been default constructed and is empty
         * You can do computations here and then...
         */
        if(/* some elaborate condition*/) {
            a = A();
            /* access *a from here on */
        } else {
            /* anything you want */
        }
    }

private:
    boost::optional<A> a;
};
```

This answers the question but I think a more appropriate answer could be given if you told what you really wanted to achieve. I feel this is more of a design issue rather than a language issue. Extended thoughts follow.

In the above 'solution', what goes in the `else` clause? Since `A` can apparently only be default-constructed, it's not like you can put a different constructor call. If you do not however initialize `a` you introduce (cyclomatic) complexity since that would mean that every method will have to check if `a` is active. Alternatively you could throw; I would however refactor the code that do the checking (or whatever) in a function; either a private static method or an anonymous/static freestanding function like this:

```
namespace {
A
prepare_A()
{
    /* elaborate computations, possibly throw */
    return A();
    /*
     * if A had different constructors we could also conditionally
     * return an A(0) or whatever.
     */
}
} // namespace

B::B()
:
    a(prepare_A())
{
    /*
     * a is of type A, not boost::optional<A>
     */
}
```

This however assumes that `A` is copyable. If that's not the case or it's not acceptable to copy `A` around, I'd consider the first solution acceptable on the condition that as part of the class invariant `a` is never empty.

It'd be easier to recommend something if we knew the relationship between `A` and `B`. Why would you put an `A` member in `B` if you want to conditionally initialize it? Perhaps the preferred relationship between the two should not be aggregation but association: a pointer member (or reference member if you're careful about the assignment operator) to `A` such as:

```
class B {
public:
    explicit
    B(A& a_)
    /*
     * Important: not A const&,
     * we only want lvalues.
     * Contract on the caller: a must remain valid during
     * the lifetime of *this.
     */
    :
        a(&a_)
    {
        /*
         * class invariants: a != 0,
         * *a remains valid for the lifetime of B
         */
    }

private:
    A* a;
};
```

That way you introduce no cyclomatic complexity and you don't care how and when an A is constructed. The contract adds a bit of a burden on the caller but since we can only pass lvalues to the constructor it's hard(er) to misuse.

Answer (score 4):

As Konrad Rudolph pointed out:

```
class B
{
public:
  B(bool create = false)
  {
    a = (create ? new A : NULL);
  }
  ~B()
  {
    delete a;
  }
private:
  A* a;
};
```

Comment: this code works with managed code. I want to avoid pointer's altogether as far as possible, because this code will be handed over to a team which works mostly with managed code/scripting only.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear which constructor you want to avoid but in either case you can use a union.

From Stroustrup 4th ed:

> If a union has a member with a user-defined constructor, a copy operation, a move operation, or a destructor, then that special function is deleted (§3.3.4, §17.6.4) for that union; that is, it cannot be used for an object of the union type.

So if you want to *not* construct A when it is in B, use:

```
class B {
public:
    B()
    {}

    // Data members
    union {
       A a;   // This instance of A is the issue
    };
};
```